# Exclusion of rows with many-to-many relationships

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have three tables: posts, tags and posts_has_tags (which facilitate the many-to-many relationship between posts and tags). A post can have any number of tags.

The 'posts' table has the following columns:
idposts
text

The 'tags' table has these:
idtags
name

As for the 'posts_has_tags' table:
posts_idposts
tags_idtags

What I can't do is come up with a query to select all posts except for those which have a tag (or tags) with a certain value in the 'name' column assigned to them. It seems that it should contain a "NOT EXISTS", but I can't really fully wrap my head around it.

Thank you for your help in advance.

EDIT:

Also, is it possible to restrict the result set to certain tags at the same time? For example:

tags for exclusion: a, b 
tags for inclusion: c

Post with tags 'a', 'f' doesn't make it into result set (because none if it's tags are included).
Post with tags 'a', 'b', 'c' doesn't make it into result set either (because it's 'a' and 'b' are excluded tags).
Post with tags 'c', 'f' does make it into result set, because 'c' is the included tag.

**FINAL EDIT**
I finally found a solution that seems to be working and reasonably well-performing: http://www.mysqldiary.com/a-many-to-many-relationship-table-solving-the-exclude-relation-problem/

Comment: not clear (edited part), will you please explain it better way.(redirection?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that seems to be working and reasonably well-performing: http://www.mysqldiary.com/a-many-to-many-relationship-table-solving-the-exclude-relation-problem/

Comment: The solution mentioned in the above link is for the single table. can you tell me how it fixed your issues as you have three tables. I have similar issue which you have mentioned above before edit

Comment: @seasagar In the linked article (now available [at a new url](https://www.rndblog.com/a-many-to-many-relationship-table-solving-the-exclude-relation-problem/) the link table can be thought of as having IDs in both columns, rather than a varchar as in the example.

This method has the benefit of only evaluating once per row. And I'd think you could change the SUM() statement to be an IN() function that contains the IDs fo the tags you want to exclude or include.

Comment: I build out a quick SQL Fiddle to validate this, albeit on a small dataset. Each of the relevant attributes is found. Columns for include and exclude are generated for each row, those are then summed, and the resulting values are used to filter the results via a HAVING clause.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/290591/11

Answer (score 4):

You can use an anti-join.

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN post_has_tags pt ON (pt.post_id = p.id)
LEFT JOIN tags t ON (t.id = pt.tag_id AND t.name IN ('test','test1','test2'))
WHERE t.id IS NULL
GROUP BY p.id
```

If you want to force other tags to be included, you do another join.

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN post_has_tags pt ON (pt.post_id = p.id)
LEFT JOIN tags t ON (t.id = pt.tag_id AND t.name IN ('a','b'))
INNER JOIN tags t2 ON (t2.id <> t.id AND t2.id = pt.tag_id AND t2.name IN ('c')) 
WHERE t.id IS NULL
GROUP BY p.id
```

This will prioritize exclusion over inclusion.
If you want to prioritize inclusion then replace the inner join with:

```
INNER JOIN tags t2 ON (t2.id = pt.tag_id AND t2.name IN ('c'))
```

Comment: Don't you need a `GROUP BY p.id` ?

Comment: @ypercube, yes you'd need a `SELECT DISTINCT` or the faster alternative `GROUP BY p.id`

Comment: Thanks! Could you also look into the problem described in the edit I made?

Comment: It seems I have chosen this answer as valid too quick. It appears that the first variant, which prioritizes exclusion over inclusion, doesn't work. The result set is always empty, no matter what tags I put in "IN..." statements. I would be very grateful if you would help me with this difficulty, since I can't really fully understand your code yet.

Comment: Neither the very first variant does work, without is inner join. It doesn't remove any posts at all, regardless of what tags are assigned to it.

Comment: @Johan, I hope these comments will reach you. I also seem to have found out why the very first variant doesn't work. If there are two tags assigned to a post, one of which is excluded, it removes the row with the excluded tag, but keeps the row with another, so the row makes it into the result set even though it has an excluded tag assigned to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM posts AS p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM posts_has_tags AS pt
          JOIN tags AS t
            ON pt.tags_idtags = t.idtags
        WHERE pt.posts_idposts = p.idposts
          AND t.name = @CertainForbiddenTagName
      )
```

If you have many tag names to forbid, use this instead:

```
          AND t.name IN (List of ForbiddenTagNames)
```

---

For your updated 2nd question, just add a similar `EXISTS`:

```
   AND EXISTS
       ( SELECT *
         ...
       )
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you also look into the problem described in the edit I made?

Comment: Is it possible to prioritize inclusion over exclusion with that query?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from posts where idposts in 
(select posts_has_tags.posts_idposts from posts_has_tags   
join tags on tags.idtags = posts_has_tags.tags_idtags  
 where tags.name not in ('value1','value2',...))
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you also look into the problem described in the edit I made?